# MVC - Parse Objects From Database

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, model-view-controller

I am trying to make my best OOP code to parse objects with data from database so I created a hook that call a `class AppAutoLoadObjects` from hooks folder.

config/hooks.php

```
$hook['pre_system'][] = array(
    'class' => 'AppAutoLoadObjects',
    'function' => 'initialize',
    'filename' => 'AppAutoLoadObjects.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

hooks/AppAutoLoadObjects.php

```
class AppAutoLoadObjects
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this,'autoloadCoreObjects'));
    }

    public function autoloadCoreObjects($class)
    {
        $path = array(
            'objects/',
        );

        foreach($path as $dir) {
            if (file_exists(APPPATH.$dir.$class."_Object".'.php'))
                require_once(APPPATH.$dir.$class."_Object".'.php');
        }
    }

}
```

As you see in the code I have a `objects` folder where I require the object parser.

So if I have `models/Products_model.php`, the `autoloadCoreObjects` automatically loads `objects/Products_Object.php` .

Then in my `Products_model.php` I use on each function:

```
  public function select_by_limit($start, $limit, $resolution) {
    ..........................................
    $query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->custom_result_object('Products_Object');
  }
```

So my object with items from database are parsed in `Products_Object.php`

```
class Proprietati_Object
{

    private $_resolution;

    public function __construct($resolution = 270){
        $this->_resolution = $resolution;
        $this->_ci = get_instance();
    }

    //here is where I check if any image in database and if not give a default
    public function image(){

        if($this->image_name):
            return base_url('assets/uploads/'.$this->id_proprietate.'/'.$this->image_resolution());
        else:
            return base_url('assets/images/no-product-image-available.png');
        endif;
    }
    //here is where I load a small part of view as string because I must show in view different html code for each product_type
    public function get_block_caracteristics(){
        if($this->product_type == 'apartament')
            return $this->_ci->load->view('blocks/apartament', array('product' => $this), TRUE);
        elseif($this->product_type == 'land')
            return $this->_ci->load->view('blocks/land', array('product' => $this), TRUE);
    }

    //here is where I set the image resolution and depends on each page where I show the products. E.g. 100, 200, 500
    private function image_resolution() {

        $image = explode('.', $this->image_name);
        return $image[0].'_'.$this->_resolution.'.'.$image[1];
    }
}
```

With this approach I have my controller clean and I only use:

```
$products = $this->products->select_by_limit(0, 10);
$data['products'] = $products;
```

then in view:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>

<?= $product->image() ?>
<?= $product->get_block_caracteristics() ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My question is how can I pass the `$resolution` variable from the model to the Products_Object constructor? Or maybe my approach is not a good one?

I now this is a very detailed question but I am dealing with this from long time ago, and my purpose is to start coding with clean controllers and models. The framework I use is CodeIgniter.

Comment: i already explained everything in this thread http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63496.html

Comment: Yes but in last discussions I did not understand how can I pass the $resolution to class and why is not ok to load some parts of html as string in that class? And if is not a good approach to load parts of html there where can I?

Comment: i posted an answer but if you have understood what i did in my example on the CI forum - you would have known the answer by yourself ...

Answer (score 0):

your model

```
public function select_by_limit($start, $limit, $resolution) 
{
    $query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    $arrData = array();

    foreach($result->result("Proprietati_Object") AS $objProduct)
    {

        $objProduct->setResolution($resolution);
        $arrData[] = $objProduct;
    }

    return $arrData;
 }
```

and in your Proprietati_Object add a function called setResolution

```
public function setResolution($resolution)
{
    $this->_resolution = $resolution;
}
```

and thats it